# MongoDB Sharding and Replica Set Allocation

Tags: mongodb, replication, sharding

I am going to setup MongoDB cluster:

3 config servers, 3 routing servers, 2 shards (replica set per shard).

A replica set is just simply 1 primary, 1 secondary and 1 arbiter.

Therefore, in my concept, totally 12 (3 + 3 + 2*3) servers will be setup.

However, it is limited only 3 servers physically. Is there any good way to allocate those instances into 3 servers?

My idea is that:

ServerA - 1 config instance, 1 routing instance, 1 primary (shard I), 1 secondary (shard II)

ServerB - 1 config instance, 1 routing instance, 1 secondary (shard I), 1 arbiter (shard II)

ServerC - 1 config instance, 1 routing instance, 1 arbiter (shard I), 1 primary (shard II)

In a result, if one server is down, the whole MongoDB cluster still works. Since I lack in experience of database cluster and distributed system, I would like to obtain professional suggestion from all of you.

In addiction, I would like to know is it possible to allocate MongoDB data to other server storage (i.e. SAN)?

Thank you for any advices.

Comment: If any of the three config server instance is down then your balancer / mongos will not be able to perform chunk migration or splits so you will not be able to add any new data, you will still be able to read just not add. You need 3 config machines to ensure 2 phase commit and to keep your meta data on your cluster consistent. This is by design to prevent data corruption or inconsistency. So in this case, any one server down will leave your cluster running in read-only mode.

Comment: You can use SAN storage but in general local disks will give higher performance, however this depends on the particular SAN.

Comment: @eoinbrazil, many thanks, then I would like to know how may I setup load balancing and failover using shard and replica set so that once a server is down, the whole cluster still works? Thank you for your professional advices again.

Comment: @eoinbrazil, I found a paragraph talking about this issue on MongoDB official website. "If one or two config servers become unavailable, the cluster’s metadata becomes read only. You can still read and write data from the shards, but no chunk migrations or splits will occur until all three servers are available.

If all three config servers are unavailable, you can still use the cluster if you do not restart the mongos instances until after the config servers are accessible again." is it an opposite to your option? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-config-servers/

Comment: If you continue write operations and end up with a shard that has too many chunks, the balancer/mongos will attempt to automatically balance these chunks to the other shards. In general, you can use the cluster but my answer is that you should always err on the side of caution so whilst you can sent new data, if you send more than your chunk size (default is 64MB) you'll trigger a balancing round. The key point here is that you want your 3 config server instances up, without these your cluster will operate in a degraded state as it is unable to balance.

Comment: In the case where a balance round was attempted with only two config servers available, the balancer could get 'stuck' and hold a lock that wouldn't be removed automatically whilst the third config server is down. This is why I'd err on the side of caution!

Comment: @eoinbrazil I try to rephrase what you said is if one server is down, the cluster is in danger state because the balancer is actually out of work. Then I would like to know how to let the cluster still work fine in both read and write mode even if one of three config servers is down? Many thanks!

Comment: Looking back, I think a single replicaset without sharding would suit what you need. You can run it with one of the three config servers down in a degraded state but you may get jumbo chunks. You might considered taking the free course https://university.mongodb.com/courses/10gen/M202/2014_April/about from MongoDB University as I think this will answer many more of your questions and help you build a scalable cluster.

Comment: @eoinbrazil However, we want to have read and write in multiple servers. If I have a single replica set, even I set secondary to have read mode, I still cannot have multiple write. I wish to have a solution to handle read and write load-blancing. Btw, the course is really great and I wanna take it but it will start from 29 Apr and sadly I have to take a prerequisite course which will start from 5 May... Anyways, many thanks